# Spotlight calculator always scientific notation?

Tags: macos, spotlight, high-sierra

How do I get the spotlight calculator to always use scientific notation?

This is how it looks by default:

[image]

But I would rather that the answer above was displayed as `2.07935e-10`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to force a result too big or small to be shown in decimal format.

So multiply everything by 1e100 to force scientific format, and then just subtract 100 from the exponent that appears:

[image]